# Android ndk static linking to openssl failed with BIO_new_dgram undefined

Tags: android-ndk, openssl

I built libssl.a and libcryto.a. But when I want to link my.so to it, I got this error:

```
Error:(130) undefined reference to 'BIO_new_dgram'
```

If I delete this call, I can compile it succeed.

Did I build the library of openssl in a wrong way?

BIO_new_dgram is in libcrypto.a:

```
nm libcrypto.a  | grep BIO_new_dgram
0000081c T BIO_new_dgram
```

I configure Openssl  with:

```
./config shared --openssldir=$install_dir --prefix=$install_dir
```

and link command:

```
/home/choury/bin/Android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/l
inux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/ho
me/choury/bin/Android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-andr
oid-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/choury/bin/Android/android-sdk-lin
ux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -fPIC -std=c++11 -Wall -fPIC -ggdb
 -O0  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-und
efined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build
-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noe
xecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,my.so -o
 $outpath/my.so $mypath/a.o $mypath/b.o $install_dir/lib/libssl.a $install_dir/li
b/libcrypto.a -ldl my.a -lz -llog -lm "/home/choury/bin/Android/android-sdk-linux
/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/libsupc++.a" "/home/
choury/bin/Android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9
/libs/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
```

I build the project with cmake, the Openssl part of it:

```
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}/include)
set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}/lib)
set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}/libcrypto.a)
set(OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}/libssl.a)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED IMPORTED)
```

The OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is set with $install_dir in build.gradle.

Comment: We don't know how you build the libraries, so there's no way for us to tell.

Comment: I buid it refer to  https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

Comment: Did you configure OpenSSL with `no-dgram` of `-DOPENSSL_NO_DGRAM`? Perform `nm libssl.a | grep -i BIO_new_dgram` and see if the symbol is available. Otherwise, state where OpenSSL is located, and show your link command for `my.so`.

Comment: @jww added in the question.

Comment: In your link command, it appears you did not put `$install_dir` on the linker's path. I would expect to see it with a `-L` option. The linker is probably linking to a downlevel version of the library.

Comment: @jww I replaced it manually before post it. It is the same as the path in the config command

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm voting to close. If you can provide the requested information, then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145807/discussion-between-choury-and-jww).

Comment: @AlexCohn  I built it for aarch64 using android ndk on my x86_64 PC

Comment: Take your link command and change the order of arguments there. Let `my.a` be the first argument after all `.o` files, followed by libssl and libcrypto, and only the put `-ldl` etc

Comment: @AlexCohn That's grate, It solved my problem, Thanks l lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker in NDK is sensitive to the order of static libraries on command line. If **libA.a** depends on **libB.a**, the command line should be

```
clang++ … a.o b.o a/libA.a b/libB.a … -Llibs -lm -ldl -lz -llog -o libqq.so
```

here I assume **libm.so**, **libdl.so**, **libz.so** and **liblog.so**. Note that the following command is equivalent:

```
clang++ … a.o b.o -La -lA -Lb -lB … -Llibs -lm -ldl -lz -llog -o libqq.so
```